# Ajax & Rails checkbox updating issue

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Rails I have a question about using Ajax. I have incomplete tasks and complete tasks on a page so, at the moment when a user clicks the complete button, the page is reloaded then the checked task is moved to the complete task. However, I want this action without reloading the page. This could be very easy for you guys but please consider that I am new to Rails as well as JS. Appreciate your help.

View

```
    <%= form_tag(complete_user_tasks_path(@user.id), :remote => true, :authenticity_token => true) do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "select_time", @select_time %>
      <div class="edit_task">
        <% for task in @incomplete_tasks %>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <div id="incomplete_tasks">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <% if task.id == @random_task.id%>
                  <div class ="edit_task">
                    <%= check_box_tag 'task_id', task.id, :id => "checked_task" %>
                  <%end%>
                  <%= task.title %>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          <% end %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Mark as Complete', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-sm-6">
    <h1>Complete Tasks</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <% for task in @complete_tasks %>
        <div id="complete_tasks">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <%= task.title %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could is add `remote: true` to your form_tag and this will not reload the page.

```
<%= form_tag complete_user_tasks_path, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

Along with this, you'll have to add a new action in the controller

```
def complete
  user_id = params[:user_id]
  @user = User.find(user_id)
  @update_task = Task.where(id: params[:task_id]).update(complete: true)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

In your view, create a complete_user_tasks.js.erb, which would read the values from the controller and reload the data.

```
$('#id_or_.class').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'section_which_needs_to_reload_data_is_stored_in_this_file', :locals => {update_task => @update_task, user => @user}) %>");
```

or if you're not using a partial, you can do the below

```
$('#id_or_.class').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@update_task)) %>");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just few questions. the (Q1) the form(checked data) will be passed to the action named complete in the task controller as I declared like <%= form_tag complete_user_tasks_path %>, but still need to make a new action? (Q2) what should i put insdie of 'partial"" and locals=>{} $('#').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: '', :locals => {}) %>"); ??'

Comment: Sorry about silly questions. I am a bit confused with this concept.

Comment: Thanks for your help. this is last question (hopefully), so should declare the id or class for form_tag? or the check_box? at the moment, I am getting this kind of error :"rails-ujs.self-551fbd47b981dacbb84a270f9123074caf39eb72aaf6f478ab597c6f81435e4b.js?body=1:212 POST http://localhost:3000/users/24/tasks/complete 500 (Internal Server Error)" <I have checked the console and the status is 500> should i update anything?

Comment: it should be for the check_box.

Comment: I also have checked the terminal : ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial tasks/_task with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:

Comment: Do you have `_tasks.html.erb` file ?

Comment: No sir, do I need to make one?

Comment: `$('#checked_task').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@update_task)) %>");` I used this one as I don't use any partial and put ` <%= check_box_tag 'task_id', task.id, :id => "checked_task"%>` made like this

Comment: Well, If you want to move the html part into a partial and render it then `yes`, you'll have to make one, however, if you decide to keep them in one file, then you have to use the second option which is `append` to your `check_box`

Comment: I used the second option, and what it does is, it doesn't display that the incomplete task is moved like seems not working but when I refresh the page the task is moved to complete section...

Comment: Sorry to bother you sir

Comment: Oh, for creating a new view. (complete_user_tasks.js.erb), does that needs to be same as the action name like complete or it needs to be the same as path

Comment: The view's `name` should be the same as the action `name`.

Comment: Can you try this `$('#id_or_.class').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(@update_task)) %>");`

Comment: that doesn't work.. makes the same error. what I keep having is _ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial tasks/_task with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:_ this is from the terminal and `$('#checked_task').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(@update_task)) %>");` .. and i made the file as **complete.js.erb** since the form is submitted to **complete** action.

Comment: Man, I have updated the code, can you please have a look

Comment: The error, you're getting seems to be inside a view file where you're trying to render a `partial` with the name `_task`

Comment: If it's possible, can you put your code into a repo and share it ?

Comment: I really wanted to do, but somehow it makes a git error, I can’t really push it sorry about that. I was using [https://rubyplus.com/articles/4211-Using-Ajax-and-jQuery-in-Rails-5-Apps] this resources to make it happen but I don’t want the creating a new task and updating the task in the same page. All I need is when the user moves the task from incomplete to complete, no reloading the page :( I really appreciate your help man..